# Read access violation in ffiw64.c when using GTK+ in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio, exception, gtk

I have followed the instructions in [Setting up GTK for Windows](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows/#using-gtk-from-vcpkg-packages) to setup GTK+ in Windows using vcpkg.

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
vcpkg install gtk:x64-windows
```

And integrated it with Visual Studio

```
vcpkg integrate install
```

The is no problem compiling the application, I am using a sample code from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html).

At runtime, before even the window shows up, I get an exception at line 173 at ffiw64.c.

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
>   **pn** was 0x111011101110111. occurred

Anyone knows what might be the issue?

**EDIT:**

Answered my own question, but I will leave it just in case it is helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the issue.

I was indeed using `x64` solution platform, but solution configuration must be set to `Release`.

Any idea why this issue occurs? I thought `vcpkg` installed the necessary dependencies for `Debug` configuration.